# The elusive 'Delete' button on "Individual Application" (Grantmaking)

Tags: lightning-experience, button, delete

We're in the process of implementing Grantmaking.  Part of the package includes an "Individual Application" object.  This object doesn't have any "Delete" button (we tried overwriting standard buttons on the page layout; we have 'delete' privs on the object).  Is there a reason why we can't delete or is there a way to add it?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have appropriate sharing access to delete this record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I work at Salesforce for a different team that also interacts with `IndividualApplication` entity*

The delete standard button is completely excluded in the internal codebase for `IndividualApplication` so you'll never see it. However, it's *just* the **button** that is excluded. You can still delete records through non-button mechanisms (APIs). There's even a [help document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000396578&type=1) covering this concern. It mentions using Salesforce Inspector - but, there's some other options that also come to mind

- [REST API call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_delete_record.htm)
  `curl https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v59.0/sobjects/Account/001D000000INjVe -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -X DELETE`
- [Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.inserting_updating_or_deleting_data.htm&language=en_US&type=5)
- [sf command](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_data_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_data_delete_record_unified)
  `sf data delete record --sobject Account --record-id 00180XX`
- Dev console you can also delete the record after a query.

Naturally, you might ask "why" the delete button is excluded. I believe this was related to `IndividualApplication` having a usage-based pricing approach (at least, for the initial cloud that created the entity which was Public Sector Solutions). Either way, there does seem to be an internal work item being talked about (W-14059768, safe harbor) for pursuing allowing the "delete" button for Grantmaking IndividualApplication records (done through [ApplicationRecordTypeConfig](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.psc_admin_task_config_appl_recd_type.htm&type=5)) if you are interacting with Support.